# Cannot get data using LinkedIn api

Tags: api

I am trying to get data using API provided by LinkedIn. I have got the API key, API secret, and the access key as well. After going through the documentation I got to know that now they perform authentication with OAuth 2.0. I am trying to access the following API :

https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me?oauth2_access_token= my access token

The response returns the follwing:

> {"serviceErrorCode":100,"message":"Not enough permissions to access: GET /me","status":403}

I have also sought permission for the API.

Why is this happening?

***Note:*** The **"Default Application Permissions"** of my app is set to **"r_basicprofile"**.

Answer (score 0):

Please wait for about 2 hours after registration to get the permissions. Sometimes it take time to register for access.

Comment: I have done so.Still it is not giving me data. Can any individual get data from linkedn? or to get data I need to open a company page? Have you been able to use their apis?

Comment: [https://github.com/linkedin/api-get-started](https://github.com/linkedin/api-get-started) check with these implementations may be you are doing something wrong

Answer (score 0):

if i am correct, for the V2 you need a linkedin partnership : https://developer.linkedin.com/partner-programs

if you do not need the partnership program. use the v1 api.

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~
```

this will work with your current permissions.